# Can't write login info into log file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

I can't write the informations of a login inside a log file in Spring Boot, I only want to be written in the file those informations, not the other logs that are in the console.
Whatever I have tried didn't work and the file either has all the logs inside or any logs, the wanted informations are never written inside.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.
This is how I have done it:

log4j2-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<!--
    <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name="login" intLevel="50" />
    </CustomLevels>
    -->

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{white} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="./logs/historic.log"
                     filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>

                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="login" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:3.0.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.1'
}

configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

AuthenticationServiceApplication.java

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("login");
....
logger.log(Level.forName("login", 200), user.getUsername() + " logged in as admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check the concept of [logger additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity). If you don't disable it, all messages for a particular logger, will also be sent to its parent's appenders. Use:

```xml
<Logger name="login" level="INFO" additivity="false>
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Logger>
```

You also use a custom level (`Level.forName("login", 200)`) that certainly does not help understanding what is filtered and what is not. Use standard levels:

```java
logger.log(Level.ERROR, "{} logged in as admin", user.getUsername());
```

or simply

```java
logger.error("{} logged in as admin", user.getUsername());
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Piotr P. Karwasz, I have tried what you have written but it still can't write into the file, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can enable Log4j 2.x debugging by adding `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to the JVM arguments. It is the easiest way to check if your configuration file is read at all.

Comment: I think @Piotr P. Karwasz that the configuration file is read correctly because it creates the log file with the name that I have assigned, I'm trying to change all the combinations of levels but I still can't write the right informations into it, maybe it's a level problem?